# Systemd/agetty: halt machine when session ends

Tags: systemd, getty

Using LXC running a systemd based container, one automatically gets dropped into a console session on the container. By creating and modifying `/etc/systemd/system/console-getty.service` to have an `ExecStart` line such as the following:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear -a <username> -s console 115200,38400,9600
```

It's possible to skip the login session and directly drop in to a session running as a particular user.

What I would like is for the machine to be automatically halted when this session ends. Is there a way to configure this, either in systemd or agetty? For reference, the host is Ubuntu 12.04 and the container is running a pretty recent Arch basis.

Comment: terrible hack: `echo "sudo halt" >> .bash_logout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found in `console-shell.service`:

```
ExecStopPost=-/bin/systemctl poweroff
```

BTW, you don't need to make a copy of `console-getty.service` in order to make these modifications. Try the following:

```
# rm /etc/systemd/system/console-getty.service
# mkdir /etc/systemd/system/console-getty.service.d
# cat > /etc/systemd/system/console-getty.service.d/custom.conf << EOF
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear -a <username> -s console 115200,38400,9600
ExecStop=-/bin/systemctl poweroff
EOF
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

The first, empty, `ExecStart=` entry clears the value inherited from `/lib/systemd/system/console-getty.service`. For more information about this method of customizing systemd unit files, see [systemd.unit(5)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html):

> Along with a unit file `foo.service` a directory `foo.service.d/` may exist. All files with the suffix `.conf` from this directory will be parsed after the file itself is parsed. This is useful to alter or add configuration settings to a unit, without having to modify their unit files. Make sure that the file that is included has the appropriate section headers before any directive.