# Append a line in a service file

Tags: text-processing, awk, systemd, docker, nginx

I've built a docker container and I need to make changes to the `service.nginx` file.

I have the following variables defined:

```bsh
LINE=$(cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service | grep -n "ExecStart=" | cut -d: -f1)
APPEND=$(cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service | grep "ExecStart=")
CONFIG=" -e\ /nginx/nginx.conf"
FILE="/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service"
```

Output of these are:

```
13
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx
-e\ /nginx/nginx.conf
/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service
```

I want to change line 13 in the service file from

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx
```

to

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -e\ /nginx/nginx.conf
```

I tried several `awk` commands with `NR` and `gsub` and for the life of me I can not generate the file.

I was thinking something along the lines of the following:

```
awk 'NR==$LINE{gsub("$APPEND", "$APPEND$CONFIG)};1' $FILE > tmp && mv tmp $FILE
```

It's just generating a new file without the changes.

Comment: Could you more generally say that you want to change the definition of the ExecStart line of the nginx service? I'm afraid fixating on line 13 may lead you astray.

Comment: I'll also note here that you may not want to change the /usr/lib version of the file, preferring an /etc/systemd/ version of it...

Comment: [Put down the `awk` and step away from the package-supplied service unit file](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html).  Your _actual_ task is that you want to override a setting for a service unit.  Like the people at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398540/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/298581/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/66029/5132 did.

Comment: Thanks I just move the entire file into /etc/systemd/system , wasn't aware that this was frowned upon, lesson learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The systemd files located in `/usr/lib/systemd` are not meant to be modified by the user. Unit files can be placed in the `/etc/systemd/system` to override configurations in the OS supplied unit file. In your case, you need a file named `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service` containing only the following:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -e /nginx/nginx.conf
```

The reason that your `awk` example doesn't work is because you are trying to use shell variables inside of single quotes, where they do not expand and remain literal. You can use the `-v` option for `awk` to pass in shell variables:

```
awk -v "LINE=$LINE" -v "APPEND=$APPEND" -v "CONFIG=$CONFIG" 'NR==LINE{gsub(APPEND, APPEND""CONFIG)};1' $FILE > tmp && mv tmp $FILE
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the service file location. Also cheers for the solution, I have to pass the variables into awk. Lesson learned.